# Getting 100% + CPU usage on Linux server

Tags: postgresql, cpu-usage

Getting 100% + CPU usage after restoring dbdump file into postgress docker container.

Result of `htop` command from the server.
[image: High CPU usage activity]

Seems like `autovacuum reader` is consuming more CPU. Can anyone suggest what to do to reduce server CPU load time?

Comment: there are configuration options to control autovacuum described in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-autovacuum.html)

Comment: see: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/48909/13259 on dba.se

Comment: I didn't look at the code, but to the best of my knowledge there is no autovacuum reader. Your database may have been hijacked

Comment: Why would you obscure the pid and the user?  I concur with Laurenz, you've been hacked.  Those processes are probably cryptocurrency miners in disguise.

Answer (score 0):

I did restart my postgress docker container and that resolved my problem. but it's for sometime.

Here is how we resolved our this issue: https://dev.to/jaytailor45/the-anatomy-of-a-postgresql-hack-how-it-happened-and-what-we-did-about-it-b9k

Happy coding!!!